# OSX/macOS version for a decent development/compile-farm machine

Tags: software-development, osx, macos, operating-system

I'm looking for "the best" Apple OS for helping me in coding and testing cross-platform (Linux, W32, OSX) applications, written in C, C++, Python and similar (no fancy, new-fangled node.js or - horror of horrors - iApp foo).

The applications mostly deal with sound and images, so the system should be recent enough to support all the current multimedia frameworks.

The sole purpose of the system is development, though I intend to include it into a compile farm (GitLab-CI based).

For this purpose, I have secured a *Macbook Pro 6,2* (mid-2010) that comes with *Snow Leopard*, and before I start right out, I'm thinking of upgrading the OS to a "current" version.

I'm a bit illiterate when it comes to OSX/macOS, but my impression is, that the recent releases are mainly targeted at iOS users, so I wonder whether I should upgrade to `Sierra` or even `High Sierra`.
AFAICT, my hardware would support the upgrade, but I have no need for Siri, Nighshift of recent features of iTunes.

I haven't found any relevant information about the features relevant for developing on the system (including frameworks) those new releases bring with them.

So: what OSX/macOS version would you recommend for a Developer centric machine?

Comment: *Hust, hust* You remember this site is about recommending software – not about which specific version of a given OS to use? "Whether I should upgrade or not" is rather outside the scope of this site.

Comment: @Izzy oh my. i obviously forgot that i ever read about that (and still cannot find it in the docs). I'm currently facing the problem "which OS should I install on my macbook for developing for OSX" (the means to acquire that purpose will most likely be through upgrading, but that's not question I'm asking).

Comment: As I'm not familiar with Macs, I'll leave it to those who are – and for now see it along the lines of "which Linux distro best fits my requirements" :)

Comment: As a Mac fan, I can say Izzy is correct, asking for specific versions of macOS is off-topic here. Furthermore, the Answer to "Which macOS?" is always: "**Use the latest possible for your hardware**, and beware of older versions no longer getting security updates from Apple.". I don't know what you mean about updates to macOS being targeted to iOS users. iOS is targeted to iOS device users, macOS to Mac computer users. Both operating systems share much of the same core technology and both are informed by advances in the other. But each serves a different purpose and design center.